# C#.Net setup project globalization issue

Tags: c#

I have a c#.net project where I have implemented the globalization for Arabic,English, and French. It works fine as far as I run its exe or run it through VS 2010. But when I add the same project output to a .Net (VS 2010) setup project and I install it, the globalization doesn't work at all. I have tried it in both debug and release mode. Any help would really be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the "Localized Resources"?

You can find that at Setup Project -> Add -> Project Output -> Localized Resources