# Setup project globalization

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-project, globalization

I created a windows forms project and a setup project to handle the installation process.

The application it self is multilingual (English & Arabic),but the setup project is only in English.

I want to create an Arabic version of that setup project,the languages available in the localization property don't have Arabic,Any ideas about how to add a language or localize the setup forms?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a resx file :)

Comment: I think that is possible if it is a form in a windows forms application,,but in the setup project there is nothing like that,,the only option available there,is to change the "Language" property of the setup project to one of a predefined set of languages that do not have "Arabic".

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604941/c-net-setup-project-globalization-issue

Comment: thanks for your attention,but i think that question is about localizing the windows application itself not the setup project

Comment: im sorry to hear that but i think if possible, you may have to use a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Yes,,i was able to do it with InstallShield..but it is not free :(